# vue getter return undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can someone tell me why this getter is returning me "Cannot read property 'testVar' of undefined"?

```
productPrice: (state) => (id) => {
    const testVar = true
    if (this.testVar) {
        const priceObj = state.precioProducto.find(product => producto.idProducto === parseInt(id))
    } else {
        const priceObj = []
    }
    return (precioObj && state.productoPrecioReady) ? priceObj : null
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `this.testVar`, but testVar is declared as a constant in the getter block, so you must just declare your `if` condition as:

```
productPrice: (state) => (id) => {
  const testVar = true
  if (testVar) {
    const priceObj = state.precioProducto.find(product => producto.idProducto === parseInt(id))
  } else {
    const priceObj = []
  }
  return (precioObj && state.productoPrecioReady) ? priceObj : null
}
```

Comment: thanks you so much, 
I already tried and I had another error with the const inside the conditional but I didn't realized that the name of the const was different